# Can't initialize static member in c++

Tags: c++, static

When i run the code(first program) ,it shows a error that **var** is private member.I defined it is a static member so shouldn't be **var** initilized outside of the class.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class example{
    private:
      static int var;
    public:
      example(){
          cout<< "exp is called"<< endl;
      };

};

int example::var =6;

int main(void)
{
    example exp1;
    cout<< exp1.var<<endl;
    exp1.var=5;
    example exp2;
    cout<< exp2.var<<endl;
    cout<< example::var<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

but this code works succesfully;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class MyClass{
   private:
      static int st_var;
   public:
      MyClass(){
         st_var++; //increase the value of st_var when new object is created
      }
      static int getStaticVar() {
         return st_var;
      }
};
int MyClass::st_var = 0; //initializing the static int
main() {
   MyClass ob1, ob2, ob3; //three objects are created
   cout << "Number of objects: " << MyClass::getStaticVar();
}
```

What's wrong in the code(first program)?

Comment: _"Every time i run the code ,it shows a error that var is private member."_ - because it is. I guess that's just a typo?

Comment: The errors are from code in `main`, not with the initialization.

Answer (score 2):

`var` is a private member variable. It cannot be accessed or viewed from outside the class. Only the class and friend functions can access private members.

One of the options you can do to access it is to add a public method that returns its value.

```
class example {
private:
    static int var;

public:
    example() {
        cout << "exp is called" << endl;
    }
    int getVar() {
        return var;
    }
};
```

And call it from main as follows:

```
cout << exp1.getVar() << endl;
```

Comment: i edit the question .can you review your answer plz?@a Li

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in the initialization of the static data member. the issue is you are trying to access private member outside the class.

you need to add `getter` and `setter` in order to access the private data member.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/chr8rf)

Tip: if you are using c++17 you can use `inline` variable to initialize static data member.

```cpp
class Foo {
 private:
  inline static int x{};

 public:
  Foo() = default;
};
```

Comment: but last program works ....it also initilazes static private variable(st_var) ...

Comment: @yolin00 yes because you are not accessing private data member directly you are using   getter method